# Possible to programmatically open a Spinner in Android app?

Tags: android

If you have a handle to a [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner) object in an Android Activity, can you programmatically pop open the spinner options - thereby forcing the user to choose an option even though they did not click on the `Spinner` themselves?

Comment: what do u mean by spinner object, can u share mock screenshots of what u want to do

Comment: `performClick()` may not be enough, if you get the `Unable to add window` error, see the what to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16032355/8958408).

Answer (score 152, accepted):

To open the Spinner you just need to call it's [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#performClick%28%29) method.

Keep in mind that you may only call this method from the UI thread.  If you need to open the Spinner from a separate thread you should create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the UI thread and then, from your second thread, send a runnable object that calls performClick() to the Handler.

```
package com.example.SpinnerDemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SpinnerDemo extends Activity {

    private Handler h;
    private Spinner s;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        h = new Handler();

        s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Open the Spinner...
        s.performClick();

        // Spawn a thread that triggers the Spinner to open after 5 seconds...
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // DO NOT ATTEMPT TO DIRECTLY UPDATE THE UI HERE, IT WON'T WORK!
                // YOU MUST POST THE WORK TO THE UI THREAD'S HANDLER
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // Open the Spinner...
                        s.performClick();
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The resources used by this example can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).

Comment: Thanks. performClick() was what I was looking for. I should have seen that method on the spinner but missed it due to some confusion on my end. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if I used runOnUIThread for using perform click from different thread.

Comment: Worked before 5.0.2, seems to be broken on 5.0.2 (only for some devices), but working again on 5.1...

Comment: When using a dialog my spinner gets open behind the dialog using performClick(); Any solution for this?

Answer (score 26):

To show the `Spinner` items you just need to call it's `performClick()` method.

```
Spinner spDeviceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spDeviceType);
spDeviceType.performClick();
```

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to use 2 runnables as shown in the previous example.

This will be enough :

```
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        s.performClick();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I think it's just a demo to show the handler working from a separate thread.

Answer (score 11):

Simply use this

```
yourspinner.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 _spinner_operations.performClick();
}
```

you need the call in onResume, in onCreate this not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `performClick()` after the UI thread is done with its current operation(s). If you don't use `post {}`, you may not see the Spinner open.

```kotlin
findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner).post {
    performClick()
}
```