# Customized Spinner Link Button

Tags: android, spinner

I would like a customized spinner which comes up when I click a link button. So I don't want to see the spinner value or icon V at all.  Just click and the spinner pops up.

So 1) Does android have a link button.  Or how could I use Button with just button label showing and now border seamless?

2) How do I bring up the spinner from the link button?

3) How do I catch the selected spinner value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, Android does not have a dedicated link button, but buttons can be styled and themed so you can certainly make them look as links:

   Create [custom button with `<selector>`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton) to style different Button states (pressed/released).

   To make button transperent use:

   ```
   android:background="@null"
   ```
2. Register a `Button.onClickListener()` so that when clicked a [Dialog with a Spinner](http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/dialog-box-with-spinner-view-in-android-t1485.html) is opened:

   ```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Put code to show Dialog here
        }
    });
   ```
3. Register `spinner.onItemSelected()` handler as shown in the above link.

Comment: Button btnChange = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
            btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                     Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSpinner);
                     mySpinner.showContextMenu();
                  }
                });
would not work for this?

Comment: No. Spinner is a widget so it most be placed inside a container: an Activity, a Dialog, etc.. Just follow the code in the example. You can create a custom SpinnerDialog with this code, to have a cleaner design.

Comment: How would one close the dialog after selection. Also I put toast message in onItemSelected of spinner and noticed it always gets called once on itialization of the dialog, so how can I tell it a user made the selection?

Comment: Dialog is closed by calling `viewDialog.dismiss()`.

Comment: This seems relevant for your phantom spinner clicks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562248/android-how-to-keep-onitemselected-from-firing-off-on-a-newly-instantiated-spinn

Comment: I would like to open Spinner with just a single click from activity.  Dialog seems like two step open dialog and then open spinner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679804/possible-to-programmatically-open-a-spinner-in-android-app