# Clicking spinner within popup window causes WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: java, android, select, spinner

I've looked up a couple of posts for the same problem but can't seem to resolve my issue. I've used spinners throughout my application and they are working fine. It's when I try to use a spinner within a popupwindow, I get an error when selecting it. The popup window is to add references and I've declared a global ViewGroup variable (i.e. vg_references) which can be used to retrieve the components on the popup window. The code to popup the window is as follows.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
vg_references = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.reference, null, false);

pw_references = new PopupWindow(vg_references, 
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/100 * 75,
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/100 * 50,
    true);
pw_references.setFocusable(true);
pw_references.showAtLocation((View)view.getParent(), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

this.populateReferenceView();
```

This then calls a function to populate the components within the popupwindow (e.g. textfields, spinners, layouts, etc...). Part of this function is to populate a spinner with a list of strings from a database.

```
// Find the spinner
Spinner spinReferenceSourceTypes = (Spinner) vg_references.findViewById(R.id.spin_referencesSourceTypes);          

// Retrieve the list of reference source types and create an array adapter to attach to the list 
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, databaseHelper.getReferenceSourceTypes());
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinReferenceSourceTypes.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

// If there's only 1 item in the dropdown list, disable the dropdown list
if(spinReferenceSourceTypes.getCount() < 2) {
    spinReferenceSourceTypes.setEnabled(false);
}
else {
    spinReferenceSourceTypes.setEnabled(true);
}
```

When I click on this spinner, the program crashes with the following error. Can anyone please help me with this problem. Thank you all

```
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@414c67c8 is not valid; is your activity running?
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:520)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:313)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:992)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:901)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:595)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:764)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:457)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14152)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-04 18:43:41.507: E/AndroidRuntime(30504):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you calling the code to show the pop up window from a background thread?

Comment: hi @PrafulBhatnagar, no I'm calling it from an onClick event from a button

Comment: can you post the code that calling this pop up window code...

Comment: hi @PrafulBhatnagar i've just posted the code that calls it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to use a Dialog rather than a PopupWindow. It works fine that way

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem in my work, and wasted about 2 days trying to find a solution to it. But, I didn't find a solution from the web.

The solution was to specify the `Spinner` mode to be `dialog`.

from XML layout:

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

or from java code:

```
Spinner(Context context, int mode)
```

I hope my answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by replacing following line:

```
pw_references = new PopupWindow(vg_references, 
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/100 * 75,
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/100 * 50,
    true);
```

with

```
pw_references = new PopupWindow(this);
pw_references.setWidth(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/100 * 75);
pw_references.setHeight(this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()/100 * 50);
pw_references.setContentView(vg_references);
```

where `this` refer to the current `activity` reference. Just to see if this make any difference...

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Ive tried to replace the this with the reference to the current Activity, but in the constructor definitions, there's no constructor that takes in a parameter to the activity. It's all just the view or context. I've tried your suggested changed along with changing the this to view, but still no joy. Is that what you meant by changing the this?

Comment: hi @PrafulBhatnagar, I still can't seem to get this issue resolved, just wondering would you have any other ideas on how to resolve please, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The following is how the popup code is being called. I've declared the variable for the PopupWindow and ViewGroup so it can be used throughout the class

```
private PopupWindow pw_references;
private vg_references;
```

The code that calls the PopupWindow is called within an event handler for a button.

```
public void ibtn_references_Click(View view) {
    ...
    // 1st section of code in the original post
}
```

This button is inside a linearlayout (seperate layout file) that is then included within a framelayout on the current screen. Included something like the following.

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_rowButtons"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:background="@drawable/backgroud_border"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <include android:id="@+id/buttons" layout="@layout/buttons" />

</FrameLayout>
```