# I want spinner to automatically be opened when the page gets loaded android

Tags: android

I want the `spinner` drop down to get opened automatically when the page gets loaded.
what can i do for that?

```
<Spinner
    android:entries="@array/cities_arrays"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="230sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_styling"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"/>



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    placesList = new ArrayList<>();
    cities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities_arrays);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cities);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // This is to avoid automatic keypad opening as soon as the page loads.
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    placesList.clear();
    autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteText);
    autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row,placesList);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Open the Spinner when your activity will load...
    spinner.performClick();

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus_button);

     mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // inflate alert dialog xml
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Add Location");
            // set custom dialog icon
            //alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            // set custom_dialog.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            final EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView
                    .findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {

                                    //etOutput.setText(userInput.getText());
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Done",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            // create alert dialog
            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();

            city = cities[index];
            if(index != 0) {
                PLACES_OF_INTEREST_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" + city + "+point+of+interest&language=en&key=" + API_KEY + "";
                listView.clearAnimation();
                listAdapter.clear();
                new GetPlaces().execute();
                listAdapter.addAll(placesList);
                listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listView.invalidateViews();
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                System.out.println(city);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected: " + city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            index = -1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select a City!",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.application.microsoft.wayfarer, PID: 24758
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.microsoft.wayfarer/com.application.microsoft.wayfarer.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: Call `performClick()` on Spinner after setting adapter from UI thread .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680332/8089770

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to programmatically open a Spinner in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679804/possible-to-programmatically-open-a-spinner-in-android-app)

Comment: Another example of : do this for me, here is my code, as I don't have time to even explain my question.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/8170051/prathisaiharika , check my answer below , it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this like below :-

```
      Spinner  yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
      ArrayAdapter adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.planets, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
         // Open the Spinner when your activity will load...
      yourSpinner.performClick();
```

**and in your method comment this below line**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: My app is getting stopped as soon  as the page is getting loaded.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cities);
         spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Open the Spinner when your activity will load...
        spinner.performClick();

Comment: where is your cities

Comment: can you put all the code of your activity in your question , by editing it , so i can fix the code and give you.

Comment: and now run your app once and when your app is stopped , what logs are coming in your Logcat , show that also

Comment: hi can you follow the updated answer , you need to comment a line     getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: Still i am getting the same error "unfortunately stopped."

Comment: can you share the file which has cities_arrays

Comment: can you mail me to harikaprathi@gmail.com so that i will mail you the attachment files   Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your mail